# Locating the edges in FindGraphCommunities

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In `FindGraphCommunities`, how can one find the vertices associated with the edges that are found to connect one or more communities?

Comment: PRG, if any of the posted answers is acceptable please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a community graph:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g = RandomGraph[{20, 50}]]
```

Find the list of vertexes in each community:

```
mycommunitylists = FindGraphCommunities[g]
```

(*

{{3, 5, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18}, {1, 2, 7, 10, 15, 19, 20}, {4, 6, 
  8, 17}}

*)

Get an edge list of the full graph:

```
EdgeList[g]
```

(*

{1 <-> 6, 1 <-> 7, 1 <-> 10, 1 <-> 11, 1 <-> 19, 1 <-> 20, 2 <-> 8, 
 2 <-> 10, 2 <-> 11, 2 <-> 19, 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 9, 3 <-> 11, 
 3 <-> 13, 3 <-> 16, 4 <-> 6, 4 <-> 8, 4 <-> 10, 5 <-> 9, 5 <-> 11, 
 5 <-> 13, 5 <-> 18, 6 <-> 12, 6 <-> 18, 6 <-> 19, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 10, 
 7 <-> 13, 7 <-> 14, 7 <-> 15, 7 <-> 16, 8 <-> 14, 8 <-> 17, 8 <-> 18,
  9 <-> 13, 9 <-> 15, 9 <-> 16, 9 <-> 20, 10 <-> 15, 10 <-> 18, 
 10 <-> 20, 11 <-> 14, 11 <-> 16, 12 <-> 13, 12 <-> 16, 13 <-> 14, 
 14 <-> 16, 15 <-> 16, 15 <-> 19}

*)

convert to lists of adjacent vertexes:

```
hh = {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ EdgeList[g]
```

(*

{{1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 10}, {1, 11}, {1, 19}, {1, 20}, {2, 8}, {2, 
  10}, {2, 11}, {2, 19}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 9}, {3, 11}, {3, 13}, {3,
   16}, {4, 6}, {4, 8}, {4, 10}, {5, 9}, {5, 11}, {5, 13}, {5, 
  18}, {6, 12}, {6, 18}, {6, 19}, {7, 8}, {7, 10}, {7, 13}, {7, 
  14}, {7, 15}, {7, 16}, {8, 14}, {8, 17}, {8, 18}, {9, 13}, {9, 
  15}, {9, 16}, {9, 20}, {10, 15}, {10, 18}, {10, 20}, {11, 14}, {11, 
  16}, {12, 13}, {12, 16}, {13, 14}, {14, 16}, {15, 16}, {15, 19}}

*)

Search through all edges for ones linking community $i$ with community $j$, e.g. for community 1 and community 2,

```
Select[hh, 
 MemberQ[mycommunitylists[[1]], #[[1]]] && 
   MemberQ[mycommunitylists[[2]], #[[2]]] &]
```

(If, for instance, you had a large number of communities and wanted the links between community 5 and 9, then just use:

```
Select[hh, 
 MemberQ[mycommunitylists[[5]], #[[1]]] && 
   MemberQ[mycommunitylists[[9]], #[[2]]] &]
```

)

(*

{{9, 15}, {9, 20}}

*)

```
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[%]]
```

*)

{9, 15, 20}

*)

Comment: Hi David: Thank you; but, I don't recognize the code "mycommunitylists"? where is that coming from?

Comment: Ooops... now fixed.

Comment: That's nice; now, suppose my graph had four communities. How can I expand this code so that it finds only the edges that link to (cross into) all other communities? I'm essentially looking for how I can trace all the edges that leave one community and connect into one or more other communities in a set of communities.

Comment: My code works for arbitrary number of communities.  Didn't you try it?!

Comment: Yes, but for instance node 4 reaches to node 10 in another community; that is, {4,10} is a case where 4 is found in one community but there is an edge from 4 in that community to node 10 in another community. I'm looking for a listing or table of all nodes in the original graph that reach into one or more other communities...appreciate all your help too ... prg

Comment: The list of all nodes in community $i$ that reach community $j$ is in the line now marked in the solution.

Comment: David: That clarified everything; many thanks for generous time! ... prg

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Functions for finding the edges that connect communities and for tabulating the results:

```
ClearAll[connectingEdgesF, tabulateF]
connectingEdgesF = Module[{g = #},  Complement[EdgeList[#], 
     Flatten[EdgeList[Subgraph[g, #]] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[g]]]] &;
tabulateF = Module[{rule = Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[# -> #2[[1]]] &, 
        FindGraphCommunities[#], 1], edges = connectingEdgesF[#]}, 
    TableForm[(List @@@ edges) /. {a_, b_} :> Join[{a, a /. rule}, {b, b /. rule}], 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"From Vertex", "in Community", 
        "To Vertex", "in Community"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]] &;
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[5]
g2 = RandomGraph[{20, 50}, DirectedEdges -> True];

connectingEdgesF[g2]
```

> {2 -> 12, 2 -> 14, 4 -> 7, 6 -> 7, 6 -> 17, 7 -> 15, 8 -> 11, 8 -> 13,
>     11 -> 19, 13 -> 16, 15 -> 11, 16 -> 2, 17 -> 10, 18 -> 17, 19 -> 15,
>     20 -> 5, 20 -> 15}

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g2, EdgeStyle -> Thread[connectingEdgesF[g2] -> Directive[Red, Thick]], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
tabulateF[g2]
```

[image]

```
edges = {start -> 1, start -> 17, start -> 18, start -> 19, 
   start -> 15, 14 -> goal, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 13, 2 -> 14, 3 -> 5, 
   3 -> 11, 3 -> 12, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 7, 6 -> 12, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 9, 7 -> 14,
    8 -> 9, 8 -> 14, 9 -> 10, 9 -> 14, 10 -> 14, 11 -> 6, 12 -> 7, 
   13 -> 3, 15 -> 7, 15 -> 16, 16 -> 7, 17 -> 1, 17 -> 2, 17 -> 3, 
   17 -> 4, 17 -> 5, 17 -> 14, 18 -> 1, 18 -> 2, 18 -> 3, 18 -> 4, 
   18 -> 14, 19 -> 1, 19 -> 2, 19 -> 3, 19 -> 4, 19 -> 5, 19 -> 7, 
   19 -> 8, 19 -> 9, 19 -> 10, 19 -> 12, 19 -> 14, 19 -> 16};
g3 = Graph[edges];

connectingEdgesF[g3]
```

> {2 -> 3, 2 -> 13, 2 -> 14, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 3, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 9, 7 -> 14, 
>    12 -> 7, 17 -> 3, 17 -> 5, 17 -> 14, 18 -> 3, 18 -> 14, 19 -> 3, 
>    19 -> 5, 19 -> 7, 19 -> 8, 19 -> 9, 19 -> 10, 19 -> 12, 19 -> 14, 
>    19 -> 16, start -> 15}

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g3, EdgeStyle -> Thread[connectingEdgesF[g3] -> Directive[Red, Thick]], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
tabulateF[g3]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
SeedRandom[5]
g = RandomGraph[{20, 50}];
mycommunitylists = FindGraphCommunities[g];
```

The edges with both vertices in the same community:

```
withinedges = Flatten[EdgeList[Subgraph[g, #]] & /@ mycommunitylists];
```

Remaining edges have each vertex in a different community:

```
communityconnectors = Complement[EdgeList[g], withinedges]
(* or communityconnectors = EdgeList[EdgeDelete[g, withinedges]] *)
```

> {1 <-> 7, 1 <-> 14, 1 <-> 17, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 6, 2 <-> 17, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 16,
>      4 <-> 20, 5 <-> 17, 5 <-> 20, 6 <-> 16, 6 <-> 17, 7 <-> 16, 9 <-> 12, 10 <-> 11,
>      10 <-> 12, 11 <-> 12, 12 <-> 15, 13 <-> 14, 14 <-> 17, 14 <-> 19, 18 <-> 20}

Highlighting the edges that connect different communities:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g, EdgeStyle -> Thread[communityconnectors -> Directive[Red, Thick]], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Comment: kglr: Fantastic! ... now, suppose we have a directed graph. Is there a way to put a trace on each edge that links one community to another community that lists the From Community Vertex Name to the To Community Vertex Name? It would be nice to do this for all edge linking communities in a TableForm.

Comment: Here is a directed graph edges = {start -> 1, start -> 17, start -> 18, start -> 19, 
  start -> 15, 14 -> goal, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 13, 2 -> 14, 3 -> 5, 
  3 -> 11, 3 -> 12, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 7, 6 -> 12, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 9, 7 -> 14, 
  8 -> 9, 8 -> 14, 9 -> 10, 9 -> 14, 10 -> 14, 11 -> 6, 12 -> 7, 
  13 -> 3, 15 -> 7, 15 -> 16, 16 -> 7, 17 -> 1, 17 -> 2, 17 -> 3, 
  17 -> 4, 17 -> 5, 17 -> 14, 18 -> 1, 18 -> 2, 18 -> 3, 18 -> 4, 
  18 -> 14, 19 -> 1, 19 -> 2, 19 -> 3, 19 -> 4, 19 -> 5, 19 -> 7, 
  19 -> 8, 19 -> 9, 19 -> 10, 19 -> 12, 19 -> 14, 19 -> 16};

Comment: @PRG, please see the update.

Comment: kglr: This is very clever and works very nicely. I've been teaching myself to use the graph theory routines in Mathematica and this site helps a lot with this; many thanks to you and David Stork for your generous help...prg

Comment: @PRG, my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

We'll use this example graph:

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "LesMiserables"}]
```

Find the edges which are *within* communities:

```
subgraphs = EdgeList@Subgraph[g, #] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[g];
```

Visualize them:

```
HighlightGraph[Graph[g, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack"], subgraphs]
```

[image]

You want the edges which are not within a community but connecting different communities, i.e. the black ones in the visualization above.

```
connectingEdges = Complement[EdgeList[g], Union @@ subgraphs];
```

Now get the vertices incident to these edges.

```
Union@Level[connectingEdges, {2}]
(* {"Babet", "Bahorel", "Bamatabois", "Bossuet", "Brevet", \
"Brujon", "Champmathieu", "Chenildieu", "Claquesous", "Cochepaille", \
"Combeferre", "Cosette", "Courfeyrac", "Enjolras", "Eponine", \
"Fantine", "Feuilly", "Gavroche", "Gueulemer", "Javert", "Joly", \
"Judge", "Mabeuf", "Marguerite", "Marius", "Mlle Baptistine", "Mme. \
Magloire", "Mme. Thenardier", "Montparnasse", "Myriel", "Simplice", \
"Thenardier", "Tholomyes", "Valjean"} *)
```